# 3D visualization software

Tags: image, 3d, data-visualization, medical

I have a sequence of uniformly spaced spatially separated MRI images along the Z-axis(along the body)(i.e. each image is a slice along the z axis and I have many of those images at a uniform separation) and I would like to know if there is a software(preferably open source but not limited to) that could combine them together to give me a 3D solid representation of the imaged regions.

Comment: If you're looking for a programmatic solution, [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) and [ITK](http://www.itk.org/) might be worth looking at. If you're simply looking for software, then it might be off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully used [3D Slicer](http://www.slicer.org/) to look at MRI images. Also have a look at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_healthcare_software) on the subject of open source health care software. It has a section on visualization.